# I need to render an image on top of a drawn Object

Tags: c#, winforms, image, graphics

[image]

I need to make a program that'll enable the user to customize his own car.

My problem is I have to draw the customizables by code and I have to add a PNG image of  details on top of the drawn car.

1. The user has to select the colors, rim designs, and decals from the right
2. The car will be drawn when the PIMP button is pressed.
3. I have to add the PNG image, the second image, on top of the drawn image(first image), to make it look like the third image.

My current code looks like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g;
    g = this.CreateGraphics();

    if (color == 1)
    {
        g.FillPolygon(blue, body);
    }
    else if (color ==2)
    {
        g.FIllPolygon(red, body);
    }
    g.FillPolygon(blackBrush, window);

    pCard.Visible = True;
    //pCard is an existing PictureBox where the Image is the cardetails.PNG 
    backcolor = transparent
}
```

When I press the PIMP button it draws the first image, but when it draws the PictureBox of cardetails.png, the transparent color displays the color gray and covers the first image.

I am very new to C# and Visual Basic. The only thing i know how to do here is to draw that blue car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the image that contains the details you want to add:

```
Image decalImage = Image.FromFile("cardetails.png");
```

It would probably be best if you do not load it in your button1_Click method.
Then draw the image upon your graphics object using

```
g.DrawImage(decalImage, x, y);
```

Where x and y would be the position to draw it to.

Comment: I don't know how to load FromFile, my image is in my Resources named as car_details.png

Comment: Thank you so much! :D I'll post an update when I finish my project.